# Slicer based on fact table is bad for performance?

Tags: powerbi

I have a fact table that has a categorical (text) value column as 1 of the columns (there are about 1M rows).

The report has a slicer based on this column.

Is this a bad idea and rather should I extract that column into a table of its own (dimension), remove duplicates, add index, and replace the fact table column with this index column. And hen I can add the dimension as slicer.

Which of the 2 leads to better performance?

Comment: Can you test it yourself? I don't think you would notice a huge performance difference, as Power BI (that's for Import, direct query depends on the source) uses a column store and extracting distinct values in column store should be very fast.

Comment: How to test this?

Comment: Create both scenarios, click on performance analyzer in the View tab, then collect metrics for both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I did it for you. As expected, no tangible difference. Remember that column store engine used in Power BI basically acts as an index of distinct values, that's why you don't see performance difference in such a scenario.

What I did, I took the Contoso Retail data from Microsoft, created a slicer based on `DimProduct[ProductKey]` column and another one using `FactInventory[ProductKey]`.

Here are queries sent by Power BI:

**DimProduct[ProductKey]:**

```
DEFINE
  VAR __DS0Core = 
    VALUES('DimProduct'[ProductKey])

  VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
    TOPN(101, __DS0Core, 'DimProduct'[ProductKey], 1)

EVALUATE
  __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
  'DimProduct'[ProductKey]
```

**FactInventory[ProductKey]:**

```
DEFINE
  VAR __DS0Core = 
    VALUES('FactInventory'[ProductKey])

  VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
    TOPN(101, __DS0Core, 'FactInventory'[ProductKey], 1)

EVALUATE
  __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
  'FactInventory'[ProductKey]
```

`FactInventory` contains 8 million rows, while `DimProduct` 2,517 rows. Time to get unique values for both queries is

- `DimProduct` - 24 milliseconds
- `FactInventory` - 25 milliseconds

Both queries were run with Dax Studio with `Clear cache then run` option.

This is a margin of measurement error , so I think that proves what I posted in the comments.

I hope that clears things up for you :).

Comment: Note that this is for the first 101 records, as is the default sent by Power BI. But even when changing the limit to 3000 records, it's still 33 vs 33 milliseconds.

Comment: Ok so you got this using the inbuilt power bi tools dax performance analyser feature?

Comment: That and Dax Studio, as with Dax Studio I can be sure that cache is cleared before each run. But even with built in tools I was able to measure the same.

Comment: Ok and how did you get the query (define, evaluate, order by) please.

Comment: From the performance analyzer. When you open the performance analyzer pane and refresh your visual, there is a copy query button in the performance analyzer (once you expand on the query). See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-performance-analyzer